# Could the Kordylewski clouds be harvested?

Tags: colonization, natural-resources, planetary-resources

Could the Kordylewski clouds be harvested electrostatically to be used for shielding at Earth moon L4 and L5 space stations? As it's been suggested they may pose a problem for the space stations themselves, so reducing them would be good. Hoping probes needn't be overly sophisticated so they could start quite a few years before commencing space station build. Have the probes build up consolidated masses, then leave them to conserve fuel to repeat the process again. May have to put beacons on the artificial asteroids?

---

Recent news about the Kordylewski clouds:

- Deborah Byrd at EarthSky.org [Did scientists confirm Earth’s dust cloud satellites?](https://earthsky.org/earth/earths-dust-cloud-satellites-kordylewski)
- Phys.org: [Earth's dust cloud satellites confirmed](https://phys.org/news/2018-10-earth-cloud-satellites.html)
- David Darling: [Kordylewski Clouds](http://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/K/Kordylewski_Clouds.html)
- Wikipedia: [Kordylewski cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kordylewski_cloud)

Pair of open access papers by Judit Slíz-Balogh, András Barta and Gábor Horváth (October, 2018):

[Celestial mechanics and polarization optics of the Kordylewski dust cloud in the Earth–Moon Lagrange point L5 – **I. Three-dimensional celestial mechanical modelling of dust cloud formation**](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/480/4/5550/5089220)

[Celestial mechanics and polarization optics of the Kordylewski dust cloud in the Earth–Moon Lagrange point L5 – **Part II. Imaging polarimetric observation: new evidence for the existence of Kordylewski dust cloud**](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/482/1/762/5114270)

Comment: I wonder if the total mass of the observed dust has been estimated, it might be too small to be useful.

Comment: @uhoh  Would the question " what happens with the solar wind particles hitting the Kordylewski cloud" be a duplicate ? Or could it be merged  with this question ?

Comment: @Cornelisinspace I think that would be a separate question, and it *might be* better to ask it in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) than here.